# Saving progress in Lego Star Wars - The Complete Saga

Tags: ios, lego-star-wars

I have purchased the Lego Star Wars 'The Complete Saga' for my son. It has opened all the Episode doors but the 6 doors in each episode are all locked apart from door 1. Yesterday I finally made it through to door 6 in episode 4 for him and it seemed to save the progress but a few hours later the doors were locked again. Does anyone know if there is a way to unlock them and keep them unlocked?

Comment: That honestly sounds like a bug. I played those myself years back (before the complete sage was released) and I can guarantee you that each door should save the progress. I suggest you contact whoever is responsible for the games nowaday (LucasArts?).

Answer (score 1):

I'm still figuring out how saving works in TCS but I believe you can only save after you finish an episode.  When you are given an option to continue the story or return to the cantina, after you make your selection, a Death Star icon will appear at the top right corner of your screen indicating that the game is saving.  Make sure not to close the game while that icon is on the screen.